# Unzip command equivalent to "extract here"

Tags: 16.04, command-line, unzip

I have `a.zip` file. I want to extract it so I have directory "a" consist of its content similar when I do right click on directory `a` then click "extract here".

Is it possible to replicate that gui version without making directory first?
I mean this two steps:

```
mkdir a
unzip a.zip -d a
```

I need single command with arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to manually `mkdir a`; `unzip` will create the directory:

```
$ touch foo
$ zip foo.zip foo
  adding: foo (stored 0%)
$ rm foo
$ unzip foo.zip -d foo
Archive:  foo.zip
 extracting: foo/foo                 
$ tree foo
foo
└── foo

0 directories, 1 file
```